# How to parse particular values from string of dictionaries

Tags: python, string, dictionary, parsing

I'm Unable to parse items out of a string of dictionaries using python:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc",  
    "channel": 44,
    "band": 12 
    }, 
  {
    "name": "abcd",  
    "channel": 45, 
    "band": 1
    },
  {
    "name": "ab",  
    "channel": 46,
    "band": 4 
    },
  {
    "name": "abc1",  
    "channel": 44, 
     "band": 15
    },
 {
    "name": "abc12",  
    "channel": 44, 
     "band": 11
    },
.
.
```

looking to fetch channel & name only from dictionaries whose channel =44

expected output:

```
'name': 'abc', 'channel': 44
'name': 'abc1', 'channel': 44
'name': 'abc12', 'channel': 44
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = []
for item in items:
    if item['channel'] == 44:
        output.append(item['name'], item['channel'])
```

Where **items** is your list of dicts.
All the data you need will be in **output**

Comment: @aapg07 Try following: `res_data = response.json()`

Comment: First of all you should've included it in your question. But still. Try printing data and take a look at it's structure, then adjust your conditions.

Comment: This worked for me.. 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```py
dictionary = [
  {
    "name": "abc",  
    "channel": 44,
    "band": 12 
    }, 
  {
    "name": "abcd",  
    "channel": 45, 
    "band": 1
    },
  {
    "name": "ab",  
    "channel": 46,
    "band": 4 
    },
  {
    "name": "abc1",  
    "channel": 44, 
     "band": 15
    },
 {
    "name": "abc12",  
    "channel": 44, 
     "band": 11
    }
]


for element in dictionary:
    if element['channel'] == 44:
        print('\'name\': {0}, \'channel\': {1}'.format(element['name'], element['channel']))
```